# addCookie method doesn't adds the cookie to an httpServletResponse

Tags: java, servlets, controller, http-headers, httpcookie

I gotta set a cookie into a controller but when i try to add it to an HttpServletResponse object it seems to not work, neither with HttpServletResponse.addCookie(String) nor with CookieGenerator.addCookie(HttpServletResponse, String) [commented].

```
@Controller("BookSlotComponentController")
@Scope("tenant")
@RequestMapping(value = ControllerConstants.Actions.Cms.BookSlotComponent)
public class BookSlotComponentController extends AbstractCMSComponentController<BookSlotComponentModel> {
private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(BookSlotComponentController.class);
private final String MORNING_SLOT = "MORNING_SLOT";
private final String AFTERNOON_SLOT = "AFTERNOON_SLOT";
private final String EVENING_SLOT = "EVENING_SLOT";
private final String BOOK_SLOT_SELECTED_DATE = "BOOK_SLOT_SELECTED_DATE";

@Resource(name = "bookSlotFacade")
private BookSlotFacade bookSlotFacade;

@Resource
private TimeService timeService;

@Override
protected void fillModel(final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model, final BookSlotComponentModel component) {
}

@Override
protected void fillModel(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Model model, final BookSlotComponentModel component) {
    LOG.debug("Start: fillModel");
    Date refDate = null;
    String refDateStr = null;

    if (null != request.getSession().getAttribute(BOOK_SLOT_SELECTED_DATE)) {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        refDateStr = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute(BOOK_SLOT_SELECTED_DATE);
        try {
            refDate = timeService.getCurrentTime();
            refDate = sdf.parse(refDateStr);
        } catch (final ParseException pe) {
            LOG.error("Exception while parsing date " + refDate, pe);
        }

        final BookSlotForm bookSlotForm = populateBookSlotForm(request, response, refDate);

        LOG.debug("bookSlotForm getMorningSlots = " + bookSlotForm.getMorningSlots().size());
        LOG.debug("bookSlotForm getAfternoonSlots = " + bookSlotForm.getAfternoonSlots().size());
        LOG.debug("bookSlotForm getEveningSlots = " + bookSlotForm.getEveningSlots().size());

        int biggestListSize = 0;

        if (bookSlotForm.getMorningSlots().size() >= bookSlotForm.getAfternoonSlots().size()) {
            biggestListSize = bookSlotForm.getMorningSlots().size();
        } else {
            biggestListSize = bookSlotForm.getAfternoonSlots().size();
        }
        if (biggestListSize < bookSlotForm.getEveningSlots().size()) {
            biggestListSize = bookSlotForm.getEveningSlots().size();
        }
        model.addAttribute(bookSlotForm);
        model.addAttribute("dateSelected", new Boolean(Boolean.TRUE));
        request.getSession().removeAttribute(BOOK_SLOT_SELECTED_DATE);
        LOG.debug("End: fillModel");
    }
}

private BookSlotForm populateBookSlotForm(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Date refDate) {
    LOG.debug("Start: populateBookSlotForm");
    final BookSlotForm bookSlotForm = new BookSlotForm();

    bookSlotForm.setSelectedDate(refDate);
    bookSlotForm.setSelectedStr(refDate);

    bookSlotForm.setDayOfWeek(BookSlotHelper.getDayNameFromDate(refDate));

    Map<String, List<SlotData>> slotMap = new HashMap<String, List<SlotData>>();

    List<SlotData> morningSlotDataLst = new ArrayList<SlotData>();
    List<SlotData> afternoonSlotDataLst = new ArrayList<SlotData>();
    List<SlotData> eveningSlotDataLst = new ArrayList<SlotData>();

    slotMap = bookSlotFacade.getSlotMapForSlotGroup(refDate);

    if (null != slotMap.get(this.MORNING_SLOT)) {
        morningSlotDataLst = slotMap.get(this.MORNING_SLOT);
    }
    if (null != slotMap.get(this.AFTERNOON_SLOT)) {
        afternoonSlotDataLst = slotMap.get(this.AFTERNOON_SLOT);
    }
    if (null != slotMap.get(this.EVENING_SLOT)) {
        eveningSlotDataLst = slotMap.get(this.EVENING_SLOT);
    }

    bookSlotForm.setMorningSlots(morningSlotDataLst);
    bookSlotForm.setAfternoonSlots(afternoonSlotDataLst);
    bookSlotForm.setEveningSlots(eveningSlotDataLst);

    LOG.debug("Before: bookSlotForm.getSelectedSlotStr() = " + bookSlotForm.getSelectedSlotStr());

    if (null == bookSlotForm.getSelectedSlotStr()) {
        final SlotData selectedSlot = bookSlotFacade.getSelectedSlot();
        if (null != selectedSlot && null != selectedSlot.getSlotCode() && !"".equals(selectedSlot.getSlotCode())) {
            bookSlotForm.setSelectedSlotStr(selectedSlot.getSlotCode());

//              final CookieGenerator cookieGenerator = new CookieGenerator();
//              cookieGenerator.setCookieName("collectionPointCookie");
//              cookieGenerator.setCookieMaxAge(60*60*24*365*1000);
//              cookieGenerator.addCookie(response, selectedSlot.getCollectionPointName());

            final Cookie collectionPointCookie = new Cookie("collectionPointCookie", selectedSlot.getCollectionPointName());
            collectionPointCookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365*1000);
            collectionPointCookie.setPath("https://delhaize.be/bookslot");
            response.addCookie(collectionPointCookie);
        }
    }
    LOG.debug("After: bookSlotForm.getSelectedSlotStr() = " + bookSlotForm.getSelectedSlotStr());
    LOG.debug("End: populateBookSlotForm");
    return bookSlotForm;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't put the entire url into the `setPath` call - just the path within the site where you want the cookie to be valid:

```
collectionPointCookie.setPath("/bookslot");
```

Also, the path must include the path of the servlet that set the cookie - see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setPath%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I tried but unfortunately, it's the same. I also tried with setting path as "/" and also without setting it. I need to keep this cookie in the entire site, cos is needed in the header of eache page.

Comment: How have you checked that it isn't working, have you looked at the HTTP Headers in the response?